# How would I go about adding a button id so I can tell which button has been pressed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this bunch of code

```
 <%= link_to admin_conference_statuses_path(conference_id: @conference.id), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <span id="span">Comm invoiced out Venue</span>
  <% end %>


  <%= link_to admin_conference_statuses_path(conference_id: @conference.id), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <span id="span">Cross charged to Client</span>
  <% end %>
```

And I have this in my controller

```
def create
    conference_id = params[:conference_id] #Keep the same
    @conference_status = ConferenceStatus.find_by_conference_id(conference_id)#Keep the same
    @conference_status = ConferenceStatus.new unless @conference_status#Keep the same
    @conference_status.conference_id = params[:conference_id]
    @conference_status.invoiced_out_user_id = current_user.id
    @conference_status.invoiced_out_datetime = DateTime.now
    if @conference_status.save
    # Success
    else
    # Failure

    end
  end
```

Now, when one button is pressed it grabs the id and puts it into a database.

How would I go about adding it so that when button 2 (opposed to button 1) is pressed it puts current user id into a column called "cross_charged_user_id"

If you have the answer could you post it and explain what it does, so I know for next time?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: can you pass some value from the link_to based on which in controller you will decide that which link_to is clicked.? forexample <%= link_to admin_conference_statuses_path(conference_id: @conference.id, cross_charged: false), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true %=> for Comm invoiced out Venue(second button) and true first one. in controller just check the value and save the id based on true or false.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass one extra parameter to second link. Then depending on this extra parameter you can assign the current user as `cross_charged_user`.

The html code look like:

```
<%= link_to admin_conference_statuses_path(@conference), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <span id="span">Comm invoiced out Venue</span>
<% end %>

<%= link_to admin_conference_statuses_path(@conference, cross_site_to_client: true), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <span id="span">Cross charged to Client</span>
<% end %>
```

And the controller just check the `params[:cross_site_to_client]` and assign the current user

```
if params[:cross_site_to_client].present?
  @conference_status.cross_site_to_client_id = current_user.id
end
```

Even You can cleanup your code as well

```
@conference_status = ConferenceStatus.find_or_create_by_conference_id(params[:conference_id])

if params[:cross_site_to_client].present?
  @conference_status.cross_site_to_client = current_user
else
  @conference_status.invoiced_out_user = current_user
end

@conference_status.invoiced_out_datetime = DateTime.now
@conference_status.save
```